# Насыщенность рынка IT

Tags: работа

Я довольно давно занимаюсь программированием, если это можно так назвать и заметил (возможно, это иллюзия), что на данный очень много развелось программистов  (или псевдо-программистов). По крайней мере это так чётко выражается в веб-технологиях. Так много всяких "специалистов" и как-то даже не по себе. Может это от того, что я в основном ни с кем не общаюсь, кроме них :).

Как вы думаете, что светит IT рынку в будущем? Не будет ли такого перенасыщения, как было в 90-х с юристами и экономистами? Или наоборот? Ведь все прекрасно знают, что это большой плюс специалисту в этом деле, если он умеет быстро учиться новому - так как IT развивается не по дням, а по часам. И возможно рынок станет так широк, что не будет хватать специалистов.

**Как вы думаете?**

Comment: РазвИлось (от развития) или развелось (как тараканов) ?

Comment: развелось* извеняюсь :)

Comment: Почему спорно? Я не думаю что по этому поводу может быть огромный холивар. Ведь я думаю каждому интересно послушать мнение другого по этому вопросу...Ну ладно ;)

Comment: Цитата из справки:

>Какие вопросы не стоит задавать?

>Не стоит задавать вопросы-опросы, где каждый ответ является верным, форум - не подходящее место для статистических исследований и реальной ценности подобные темы не имеют.

Comment: Извиняюсь тогда.

Comment: Да у вас тут так четко правила соблюдаются - http://hashcode.ru/questions/92747/%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC-%D0%B2%D1%8B-%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%8C - а мой закрыли...

Comment: Цитата из справки:

>Как оставить отзыв, задать вопрос, сделать предложение по сайту?

>... или задать вопрос в общем потоке с меткой "ХэшКод"; ...

Обратите внимание на метку ХэшКод.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Знаете, лет 100-150 назад думали, что из за того, что кол-во жителей в городе будет увеличиваться и все они будут хотеть иметь свою лошадь, то город будет покрыт толстым слоем навоза... Но не судьба... не случилось:)

Не парьтесь и становитесь хорошим специалистом. И будете нужны всегда. А вот черновую работу тоже нужно кому то выполнять, поэтому и существуют тонны "мелких специалистов".

Comment: Хех, толстый слой навоза никуда не делся, я живу в частном доме и два раза в год меняю фильтры в приточном воздуховоде :-)

Comment: И почём сейчас машина навоза? Или один раз купили, и он "никуда не делся"?

Answer (score 3):

Пока что перспектива перенасыщения рынка труда в IT нам не светит. Есть такая ассоциация в РФ - АП КИТ (Ассоциация Предприятий Компьютерных и Информационных Технологий). Рекомендую ознакомиться с их аналитикой. Вкратце: в случае, если страна будет развиваться по инновационному сценарию, дефицит IT-специалистов в ближайшие пять лет будет выражаться числом с пятью нулями; если по сырьевому - поменьше, но тоже дефицит.

Comment: По-моему, их аналитика - это кулик, хвалящий свое болото из известной поговорки. Для наукоемкой надстройки в стране банально нет базиса. Пользуюсь случаем, передаю привет дачнику Фурсенко.

Comment: Я себя причисляю к начинающим программистам, хорошо, если так, что мы будем востребованы. Но первое впечатление от поиска работы сложилось так, что новички нафиг кому нужны. Поэтому и сижу, постоянно набиваю и руку и голову всякой фигней, которая может и вовсе мне никогда не пригодиться.

Comment: @semenvx27, тут проблема в том, что **серьезных**, рассчитанных на годы, разработок ПО в стране почти нет. Требуется что-то быстренько поправить, надстроить, приляпать, раскрасить узорами из цветочков и т.п. 

Поэтому брать новичка и учить его (чтобы потом он ушел) никому не интересно. Реально берут детей своих знакомых.

Comment: @avp, спасибо, да вы правы. Недавно читал о создателе AIMP. молодец, классно получилось, работает в свое удовольствие. Жаль, что как вы говорите, разработок серьезных нет. Но идей лично у меня очень даже много. Только когда их делать (после основной работы) и одному что ли? А в общем то для толковых спецов думаю всегда найдется работа